# xsltproc crashes on windows 10

Tags: xml, windows, xslt, libxml2

I can use xsltproc from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/ on Windows 8. But after I upgrade to Windows 10, xsltproc stops working and crashes every time.  Has Anyone experienced this problem before, and how do you fix it?

Comment: One option to use Linux tools like xsltproc on Windows 10 or 11 is certainly using WSL, that way you install the command line version of a Linux distribution (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian) under Windows and there you can then use the distribution's package manager to install e.g. `xsltproc`. That is not to say there aren't up to date binaries for Windows for those tools around somewhere, I just don't know where. But WSL is a nice option, once you got over the installation hurdle, to have such tools available with e.g. `sudo apt install xsltproc`.

Comment: Example link to a Linux distribution in Microsoft's Store: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PN20MSR04DW